# What is wrong with this Node/Sequilize code?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

## Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
   at exports.findAll (/home/psd/react/vendingrest/app/controllers/etlFile.controller.js:45:11)
```

## Questions

- It's directing directly to the line defining findAll, what property can't it read?
- in **const EtlFile = db.etl_file**  the table name is etl_file, is this correct or should it be etlFile or something else?

## Source

```
const db = require("../models");
const EtlFile = db.etl_file;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

// Create and Save a new EtlFile
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  // Validate request
  if (!req.body.title) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!"
    });
    return;
  }

  // Create a 
  const etlFile = {
    etl_file_id: req.body.etl_file_id,
    rpt_org_id: req.body.rpt_org_id,
    distributor_id: req.body.distributor_id,
    filename:        req.body.filename,        
    sale_count: req.body.sale_count,
    customer_count: req.body.customer_count,
    inventory_count: req.body.inventory_count,
    transaction_id:  req.body.transaction_id,  
    json:            req.body.json            
  };


/**
 *  Retrieve all EtlFiles from the database.
 * @param {*} req 
 * @param {*} res 
 */
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
   const filename = req.query.filename;
   var condition = filename ? { filename: { [Op.iLike]: `%${filename}%` } } : null;

  EtlFile.findAll({ where: condition })   // this should filter in database 
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving etl_files."
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: The error is on the line `EtlFile.findAll({ where: condition })`. `EtlFile` is `undefined` and `undefined` does not have the property `.findAll` (this is what the `TypeError` error means).

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of your project folder structure with all files expanded?

Comment: Seems like `db.etl_file` isundefined. Show `models` module